# Wordpress front end and Zend Framework /members area

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

I'm planning to use wordpress as a cms front end for a website, and have zend framework used in a members area (/members). The members area is going to be 100% custom made in zend framework. How would my htaccess, index.php or bootstrap need to be configured to have the /members folder as ZFs root level? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the standard index.php you only need to drop it into /members (along with .htaccess) and make sure that the paths defined in the index.php are defined correctly (e.g. `APPLICATION_PATH` points to the projects `application` directory).

Answer (score 0):

the zend framework will have directory structure

```
   project
     |
     |--public (you can install wordpress site here)
     |--library
     |--application
     |--other stuff
```

you install wordpress site inside public folder and copy all the contents of public inside a direcory **member** including .htaccess. and you don't need to modify the content of it (i think so)

and your new directory structure will be like

```
   project
     |
     |--public_html (you can install wordpress site here)
     |  |
     |  |--all your wordpress site here
     |  |--member
     |      |---all your zend framework files here
     |  
     |--library
     |--application
     |--other stuff
```

all you need to chage is the index.php fie of  zend framework

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));
```

instead of regular one

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

and i must work however i am not so sure(worked in mine).